# Hockey App Integration with IOS

Tags: ios, hockeyapp

I am trying to integrate Hockey app with IOS. I am using Xamarin forms. The intergration with Android works fine. But as per documentation, I ahave added these lines to AppDelegates.cs

---

```
var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
 manager.Configure("AppId");
 manager.DisableMetricsManager = false;
 manager.StartManager();
```

---

When I try to log in custom events, like

HockeyApp.MetricsManager.TrackEvent("Test"), the line throws an exception and complains "children could not be evaluated"

What am I missing?

Comment: Even if you solved this yourself, it would be great if you could either provide the real answer (even if trivial) or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is HockeyApp.MetricsManager.TrackEvent("Test") the actual code?
If so, then you should use : manager.MetricsManager.TrackEvent("Test") instead.

I hope it helps.